How to Extend Wi-Fi Range for ESP32 with High-Gain Antennas
Aim: Extend or increase the Wi-Fi range of ESP32 in indoor environments.
I'm working on a project that involves extending the Wi-Fi range of ESP32-based devices. I have three different ESP32 modules to choose from:

ESP32-WROOM-32E (16MB)
ESP32-WROOM-32D
ESP32-WROOM-32U

I understand that the ESP32-WROOM-32U comes with a U.FL connector, allowing for external antenna use, whereas the other two modules use internal PCB antennas.
Questions:

If I choose the ESP32-WROOM-32U with an external antenna, what type of high-gain antenna should I use to maximize Wi-Fi range? Are there any recommended high-gain antennas for ESP32 projects?

Is there any amplification required when using a high-gain antenna with ESP32? If so, what kind of amplifiers would be suitable, and how would that affect power consumption and compliance with regulations?
Are there any specific configurations or settings needed when using high-gain antennas with ESP32-WROOM-32U?

How do these three modules generally compare in terms of Wi-Fi range and reliability? Are there any other factors that might influence their range?

If I'm experiencing inconsistent communication with the ESP-NOW protocol, could there be network disturbances affecting it?

What are some common sources of interference, and how can I minimize their impact on ESP-NOW communication?

If I choose the ESP32-WROOM-32E or ESP32-WROOM-32D, is there any way to improve their Wi-Fi range despite lacking an external antenna connector? Would these modules benefit from signal repeaters, mesh networks, or other range-extending techniques?


Any guidance or best practices on extending Wi-Fi range for ESP32, especially with high-gain antennas would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Depends on your module, but usually it will be a case of getting the right IPEX connector
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-connect-external-antenna/

We are currently using the ESP32-WROOM-32E with an external 6 dBm antenna. However, we still need to increase the range. Your advice would be greatly appreciated.
